# Create my own voice on Mathematica 12

Tags: functions, manipulate, sound, mac-os-x, webmathematica

I want to create my own voice on Mathematica 12 and use it
for this function

`SpeechSynthesize["Hello"]`

We can use theses voices on Mathematica

`$VoiceStyles`

`SpeechSynthesize["Hello", First[$VoiceStyles]] // Normal`

Somebody have an Idea how I can do it?
Must have recorded my voice at first in using

`AudioCapture[]`

Thanks

Comment: You could 1) record all the words you expect to speak and have _Mathematica_ chop up and select audio to play, or 2) implement a rather complicated neural net (WaveNet, GANs?) or 3) use neural nets for audio style transfer of your voice's style onto computer voices. All are very difficult. You might be interested in this paper https://youtu.be/0sR1rU3gLzQ

Comment: There's ``SpeechSynthesisTools`Private`$MacAvailableVoices[]`` which suggests it might look up voices that are synthesized by your Mac.  There's also `$WinAvailableVoices` for Windows (I suppose).  Don't know much more.  Have you tried asking Wolfram Support?

Comment: If you install new voices for macOS (can be done in accessibility preferences), they will show up as available `$VoiceStyles` in Mathematica. I just checked that this works. There is a long list of styles you can choose from.

Comment: As for creating your own style, I do not know how easy or difficult it is ... I would expect it is not simple. But it would not be a Mathematica-specific operation. If you can find out how to create a voice style and install it system-wide, then it will also be available for Mathematica. Thus I would search about how to do this.

Comment: we are agree its difficult project @Szabolcs